# Report Server - User permissions to access all users folders

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a application .net that search a folder on report server and reads the reports inside that folder and display on asp.net page. The permissions for the asp.net user are working fine to deploy and execute on website.

Now, I want to users to deploy on "My reports" folder, so they only see theirs reports.(The users have access to report server and use report builder).

I search and I could not find a solution for this:
I want to give permissions to an a user (the same that is running on asp.net server), to access all "My reports" folder of all users(Users Folder), so I can execute the reports inside users folder on website.

I put the asp.net server user as local administrator of the report server, but with that permission te user can only see the content of the folder, this user can not execute the report. Any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, and does not involve add users to local administrator of the machine.

I used the [IAuthorizationExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.interfaces.iauthorizationextension.aspx).
I found [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jameswu/archive/2008/07/15/anonymous-access-in-sql-rs-2008.aspx) that enable anonymous access for all users witch was a start.

On my implementation I used `WindowsAuthorization`, because I want to keep the existing authorization and give access to one specific user.  On all `CheckAccess` methods I check if the user is the one I want to give access and return true otherwise return the `WindowsAuthorization.CheckAccess(...)`. On all others methods of the interface I also used the `WindowsAuthorization`.

With this solution the user running website can access all content of reporting services.